# Obj C Modal box with options to call or email

Tags: email, modal-dialog, call

Hi everyoneI need some direction on how to go about accomplishing a task. I have a app with 5 tab bar items I need to program one of the tabs to call a modal dialog box that has three options. 1. Cancel 2. Call Us 3. Email Us. if the user pushes call us the device should start calling our 800 number if they press email us then it should open the email client and put our sales or support team automatically in the "to:" section. Please provide me with some direction or perhaps a tutorial on how to something like this. Thank you for your help.

Comment: A couple of quick question before I can help you. 1. Which part is it you need help with, all of it or just some of it? 2. Why do you want a modal view to be presented from a tabbar button, to me that kind of defeats the purpose of both a tabbar item and a modal view? As you already have a view that you can use in the actual fifth tab. So wouldn't it be better to either use that viewController or present a modal view from another button, lets say in the navbar?

Comment: I really need help with all of it. The only thing I really know how to do is get a alert box to pop up in regards to a modal box. Currently the tab bar is always displayed no matter which view you are seeing it must stay that way. I am not utilizing a nav bar apart from a go back button which is automatically created with the view controller. What I would like is when a user clicks the tab item "Contact Us" is for the current view to stay where it is but have it fade while the modal dialog initiates. I am currently using a storyboard.I think that answers all of your questions. thx 4 u'r help!

Comment: Maybe a popover controller that come up from the bottom would be just as good if not better.

Comment: I would agree with that, either go with using the fifth tab as the view or remove that and present a modal view. If you need help with that just say the word and I'll post some code. If you want a tab to fade over another, that would get pretty hard as you will have to subclass the tabbar and transition. It might be doable it would take me some time to get you a working example.

Comment: yea I definitely need some help with this. I'll go with the pop over where we use the tab item as the view. I just need to get this portion functioning.

Comment: i have currently put together a call us button that works with a telprompt and a email us button that works. Getting the two to show up in a popover through the tab button is the only issue now.

Comment: I Will add an answer as soon as I got it working for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added these tasks in a different view using two UIButtons. if you come up with a way to do a popOver please let me know. If not I will go with what I have. Thank you. The code I used for email and call (both can be found by doing a SO search) in case anyone else looks in on this thread are as follows:

**EMAIL**

```
-(IBAction)emailUs:(id)sender
{
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {
        MFMailComposeViewController *mailViewcontroller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
        mailViewcontroller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [mailViewcontroller setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"CustomerService@laserpros.com", nil]];
        [mailViewcontroller setTitle:@"Email Us"];
        [mailViewcontroller setSubject:@"Email Us"];
        [mailViewcontroller setMessageBody:@"Your message goes here" isHTML:NO];
        [self presentViewController:mailViewcontroller animated:YES completion:nil];

    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Device is unable to send email in its current state.");
    }
}
-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

**CALL**

```
-(IBAction)callUs:(id)sender
{
    NSURL *phoneNumber = [NSURL URLWithString:@"telprompt://18885585277"];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneNumber];

}
```